# dropdown list who load product woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building my custom wordpress template page and I would like to do a dropdown list (or anyone else) with selected product who, selected, appears in the bottom of the page !

Currently, I the best way I found is :

```
<form action="" method="get"><select name="type">
<option selected >product</option>
</form>
```

and at the bottom of the page in a div:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['type']))

    echo do_shortcode('[product_page id="'.$_GET['type'].'"]');

else

?>
```

The code does the job, but I'm not satisfed yet ! If a plugin already exists with shortcode, I'll take it too !

EDIT: I would like to load the product without reload the page !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is the way to do that. It also helps to know a bit of jQuery, so when the JavaScript gets the data back, it can target an element and display it there. You can put something like this in the page template, inside script tags, and call it when the dropdown changes.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type:'POST',
    data:{
        action : 'display_product',
        prod_id : jQuery(this).val()
    },
    success:function(results) {
        jQuery("#product_display").html(results);
    }
});
```

Then add the PHP function to functions.php, e.g.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_display_product', 'display_product' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_display_product', 'display_product' );

function display_product() {
    if(isset($_POST['prod_id'])) {
        echo do_shortcode('[product_page id="'.$_POST['prod_id'].'"]');
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you're doing it that way, the product id won't be passed to the getProduct function. Instead of using onchange, try using jQuery to target the dropdown, e.g. `jQuery('form select').change(function() { // paste the ajax JS here. })` that way `jQuery(this).val()` should then have the selected value

Comment: Hello thanks, I had to change some things, but it works..but a lot of problems appears, so I think I will stay with the normal for for the moment !

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add to that code, is a closing `</select>`, an `onchange` JavaScript function and `value=""` on each dropdown option.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="type" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option selected value="123" >product 1</option>
        <option selected value="456" >product 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer
1) i change my question
2) the onchange function submit doesn't work ((index):1049 Uncaught TypeError: this.form.submit is not a function
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):1049))

Comment: Hi, no problem. Check there are no elements in the form with `name="submit"`. Also, make sure you have the two brackets `()` at the end of `this.form.submit()`

Comment: Ah yeah thanks ! Do you know a way to submit without reloading the page ? I try ajax but i'm not really strong with it